# Unable to upload more than 1 mb OpenNLP bin files to solr installed with bitnami helm chart

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, azure-aks, bitnami

I installed solr using bitnami helm chart. But I am unable to upload files larger than 1mb from zookeeper.

```
I have no name!@solr-0:/opt/bitnami/solr$ ./bin/solr zk upconfig -d /opt/bitnami/ -n test_config -z solr-zookeeper

Uploading /opt/bitnami/conf for config test_config to ZooKeeper at solr-zookeeper
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:37.805; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@7c0ee1f3 name: ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:solr-zookeeper got event WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path: null type: None
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:37.805; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has disconnected
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:39.403; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@7c0ee1f3 name: ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:solr-zookeeper got event WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path: null type: None
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:39.403; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has disconnected
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:42.509; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@7c0ee1f3 name: ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:solr-zookeeper got event WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path: null type: None
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:42.509; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has disconnected
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:47.113; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@7c0ee1f3 name: ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:solr-zookeeper got event WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path: null type: None
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:47.114; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has disconnected
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:53.217; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@7c0ee1f3 name: ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:solr-zookeeper got event WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path: null type: None
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:09:53.217; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has disconnected
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:10:00.819; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@7c0ee1f3 name: ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:solr-zookeeper got event WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path: null type: None
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:10:00.819; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has disconnected
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:10:09.922; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@7c0ee1f3 name: ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:solr-zookeeper got event WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path: null type: None
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:10:09.922; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has disconnected
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:10:20.525; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@7c0ee1f3 name: ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:solr-zookeeper got event WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path: null type: None
WARN  - 2023-07-20 07:10:20.525; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has disconnected

ERROR: Error uploading file /opt/bitnami/conf/test.txt to zookeeper path /configs/test_config/test.txt
```

The test.txt file size is 1.3mb

I mentioned -Djute.maxbuffer size to 31457280 for zookeeper in value.yml file in solr bitnami helm chart.
But still unable to upload more than 1mb files.

zookeeper:
extraEnvVars:

- name: ZK_SERVER_OPTS
  value: "-Djute.maxbuffer=31457280"

Comment: "Note that this configuration, which is required both for ZooKeeper server(s) _and for all clients that connect to the server(s)_, must be the same everywhere it is specified." - so I'm guessing you'll have to set it for the `bin/solr` command as well

Comment: I have updated bin/solr but still it is working. Both solr and zookeeper size are same.